# jquery stop object from sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, object

I have an object:

```
var myObj = {
    "0": "#fff",
    "trace": "#0000cc",
    "0.1": "#3366ff",
    "0.2": "#999900",
    "0.5": "#ffcc00",
    "1": "#ff9900",
    "2": "#ff0000",
    "5": "#ff00ff",
    "10": "#ccffff"
        }
```

I need to call this object keys and create list of items with their key text on each of them:

```
var myKeys = Object.keys(myObj);

myKeys.forEach(function (item) {

   var li = document.createElement("li");

   li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));

});
```

This returns:

```
<li>0</li><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>10</li><li>trace</li><li>0.1</li><li>0.2</li><li>0.5</li>
```

How can I make this in a way that it doesn't automatically sort the object?

Comment: There is no order in objects, it can't be sorted, or randomized, or whatever the issue is. The keys however, is an array, and you can just sort that however you like.

Comment: If you want to guarantee the order you should use an array.

Comment: Using the `forEach` or `for in` mechanism in JavaScript does not guarantee order, and it seems to be going in lexicographical order here.

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/loverajoel/jstips/blob/gh-pages/_posts/en/2016-02-01-map-to-the-rescue-adding-order-to-object-properties.md

Answer (score 2):

Objects aren't explicitly sorted. Many engines will implicitly sort the keys when using `Object.keys` but this isn't a guarantee. If you want the keys in a particular order, you'll have to sort them yourself after retrieving them.